# Exceptional C++ Item 36

Tags: c++, memory-management

We are reading Herb Sutter's Exceptional C++ book as part of our class assignments.

I have a question in understanding what the typedef is actually doing and deciphering
how it is constructed:  Item 36:

If would be a great help for someone to  walk though the logic of the typefef.

```
class B
{
public:
   virtual ~B();
   void operator delete (void*, size_t) throw();
   void operator delete[] (void*, size_t) throw();
   void f(void*, size_t) throw();
}
class D : public B
{
public:
   void operator delete (void*) throw();
   void operator delete[] (void*) throw();
};

typedef void (B::*PMF)(void*, size_t);
PMF p1 = &B::f;
PMF p2 = &B::operator delete;
```

Since there is no pointer to a member function in class B (PMF),
what is PMF and how does it get created?

Is void the return type of the typedef?
are (void* and size_t) the arguments of the typedef?

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean PMF instead of PMB?

Comment: According to cdecl.org: declare PMF as pointer to member of class B function (pointer to void, size_t) returning void Warning: Unsupported in C -- 'pointer to member of class'

Comment: There are errors in the code presented (missing `;` at end of classes, and `B::F` should be `B::f`).

Comment: If you don't quite understand what a `typedef` is, then you should be getting an introductory book and start from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `typedef` keyword declares an *alias* for an existing type.

For example

```
typedef int integral;
integral i = 1;
```

The line `typedef void (B::*PMF)(void*, size_t);` declares an alias `PMF` for a type: *pointer to function (that is taking a pointer to* `void` *and* `size_t`*) returning* `void`.

See this link for a detailed explanation of how to interpret the type from a complex declaration using the *spiral rule*: [The Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

`PMF` is an *alias* for the type. It can be used to declare a pointer to any function that is a member of B and has the same parameter list and return type.

```
PMF p1 = &B::f; // Declare p1 as a PMF and set it to point to address of B::f.
B b; // Create instance of B (needed as p1 points to a member function).
(b.*p1)(nullptr, 0); // Here p1 can be used as if it was a call to B::f.
```

Answer (score 0):

As has already been explained in the comments, PMB is a pointer to a member function of B taking the given argument list. It's the name of the new type -- it doesn't correspond to anything in class B itself.

Answer (score 0):

As Borgleader already pointed out, the `typedef` allows you to refer to a member function of the `B` class that has a `void` return type and two arguments: a `void` pointer and a `size_t`.

I'm pretty sure that PMF is an acronym for public member function...

Comment: More like Pointer-to-Member-Function imo